# Using function from another c file by including its header

Tags: c, linux, function

I am writing C code (not C++) on a Linux system.  I am trying to compile one executable from 2 .c files and 1 header file: main.c, sort.c, and sort.h.

main.c's first line reads: `#include "sort.h"`

inside sort.h, each function in sort.c is defined like this example:
`extern void aFunct(int param);`

However, when I try to call a function in sort.c from main.c, I get the following error upon compilation: "undefined reference to 'aFunct'".

If i replace `#include "sort.h"` with `#include "sort.c"` my program works without issue.  However, as I understand it, this is bad form and I would prefer to avoid this.  Thanks for any help.

edit:  I am compiling this with a makefile containing the following code:

```
all: index sort.o

sort.o: sort.c sort.h
    gcc -Wall -g -c sort.c

index: main.c sort.o
    gcc -Wall -g -o index main.c

clean:
    rm index
    rm sort.o
```

edit:  I have fixed the problem.  The problem did not stem from a misunderstanding of C files and how they link, but rather a misunderstanding of the makefile/gcc commands themself.  My program works with the following makefile:

```
all: index sort.o

sort.o: sort.c
    gcc -Wall -g -c sort.c

index: main.c sort.o
    gcc -Wall -g -o index main.c sort.o

clean:
    rm sort.o
    rm index
```

Comment: Are you linking `sort.o` into your executable?

Comment: I added my makefile to my question so you know exactly how it is being compiled/linked

Comment: SleuthEye, turns out my problem was I THOUGHT I was linking sort.o to the executable, but I had a syntax error my makefile that stemmed from a fundamental misunderstanding of gcc syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include #include "sort.h" in sort.c as well.
You might be doing this already.

The important point is, you need to make sure that you are building both the .c files [main.c and sort.c]

Now both these obj files [main.o and sort.o] should be the input to linker.

As per my guess, you are not compiling sort.c , so linker is not able to see the implementation of the functions.

Comment: sort.h is already included in sort.c.  And unless I am having some crisis of understanding (very possible), I am compiling sort.c into an object file. If you want you can check my question again as it now contains the makefile

Comment: The issue was I was incorrectly linking sort.o.  I figured it out on my own but this answer was pretty close so I decided to best answer it.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

When you include one source code file to other (e.g. `#include "sort.c"`) you can have a troubles if you include `sort.c` file to more than one c-file of the same project. But as I understand you just compile one c-file in which you include `sort.c`... so it works. But, better read some tutorials, for example [How to Create Multi-Module Programs](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/module.php)

Comment: I believe I am already doing everything that the link mentions